# Would like to import splitOn without using Cabal or Stack

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

I would like to import `splitOn` without using Cabal or Stack. Is that possible? It GHCi refuses to `import` `Data.Text`, `Data.List.Split`, or `Data.Split`, what's the next step without using a Cabal or Stack? Is it possible to import it directly from within GHCi?

Thanks.

Comment: The Haskell Platform includes both of these packages - `text` and `split`.

Comment: You have to install the package that contains a module before can import it. Whether that installation occurs when you first install `ghci`, or you install it later with `cabal`, `stack`, or some other means, doesn't matter.

Comment: I know you are not looking for this, but you can do: `stack ghci split text`

Comment: I installed the standard Haskell Platform from the Haskell website using the standard download. If `text` and `split` are included in the platform, why are they not visible? `import text` and `import split` don't work. How do you make them visible without using stack or cabal? Or is that not possible? Why is it necessary to do anything special to `import` something that's been downloaded as part of the standard Platform?

Comment: `import text` is a syntax error. Do you mean `import Data.Text` and `import Data.List.Split`? You should probably be aware that the `Cabal` library is a fundamental piece of Haskell infrastructure. You can use it via `stack` or `cabal-install`, but avoiding it altogether is likely to be an exercise in frustration. Pretty much every important package in the Haskell world relies on Cabal to some extent.

Comment: Yes, I had tried `import Data.Text` and `import Data.List.Split`. The comment was wrong, but the GHCi command was right.

Comment: So for someone who just wants to write basic Haskell programs and not do major development, is there a simple tutorial that explains how to use one or the other -- and which one makes more sense for that purpose, i.e., simple programs that may need packages/modules in the standard platform?  I would like to be able to start WinGHCi and import standard things from the prompt. Is that possible? I would have thought was would be possible. It works for many modules. Why for some and not for others? And how does one tell the difference?

Comment: Here's a guide to using GHCi with Stack https://haskell-lang.org/tutorial/stack-play

Comment: Thanks. It's not your responsibility, but that's just what I didn't want. The first thing it says it to read something else about installing stack. After that it doesn't say anything about using Stack to import packages that (in my view) should be imported without any extra effort. So, a lot of reading with no real answers to my simple problem: how to import something that is downloaded with the standard platform.

Comment: Does `ghc-pkg list` show `text` and `split`?

Comment: Are you able to import them if you start GHCi with the `-package text -package split` arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
cabal install missingh
```

and

```
cabal install split
```

solved the problem. It seems like that shouldn't have been necessary, but apparently it was.